# flutter FCM new notification message.post manually is returning 401

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am trying to implement FCM notification inside my flutter app,but the endpoint is not returning what expected , its returning 401 and i don't know how to fix it if anyone encounter same issue let me know how to fix it

here's my implemented function

```
void sendPushMessage(String token, String body, String title) async {
  Dio dio = Dio();
  try {
    await dio.post(
        'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/ecommerece-c1601/messages:send',
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer ${ApiKeys.fcmServerKey}",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
        ),
        data: {
          "priority": "high",
          "data": {
            "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
            "status": "done",
            "body": body,
            "title": title,
          },
          "message": {
            "token": token,
            "notification": {
              "title": title,
              "body": body,
              "android_channel_id": "Shoppie"
            }
          },
          "android": {
            "notification": {"click_action": "TOP_STORY_ACTIVITY"}
          },
          "apns": {
            "payload": {
              "aps": {"category": "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"}
            }
          }
        });
  } catch (e) {
    print("error");
    log(e.toString());
  }
}
```

- based on migration from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1 mentioned in https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1
  my endpoint looks like this : "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/ecommerece-c1601/messages:send"
  where "ecommerece-c1601" is my project id.
- I got the fcm api enabled inside firebase and google cloud APIs & services
  also based on firebase cloud messaging docs
- I have the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable mentioned inside my environment variables where i got the private key from project settings on firebase
- Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) on my firebase is enabled as well where the server key is mentioned inside my code snippet in "API.fcmServerKey"

at https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/ecommerece-c1601/messages:send as my end point this is the response

```
[log] DioException [bad response]: This exception was thrown because the response has a status code of 401 and RequestOptions.validateStatus was configured to throw for this status code.
The status code of 401 has the following meaning: "Client error - the request contains bad syntax or cannot be fulfilled"
Read more about status codes at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status
In order to resolve this exception you typically have either to verify and fix your request code or you have to fix the server code.
```